# SQL-query task, decision?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, optimization

There is a table of currencies rates in MS SQL Server 2005:

**ID | CURR | RATE | DATE**
1   | USD   | 30      | 01.10.2010
3   | GBP   | 45      | 07.10.2010
5   | USD   | 31      | 08.10.2010
7   | GBP   | 46      | 09.10.2010
9   | USD   | 32      | 12.10.2010
11 | GBP   | 48      | 03.10.2010

Rate are updated in real time and there are more than 1 billion rows in the table.

**It needs to write a SQL-query, wich will provide latest rates per each currency.**

My decision is:

```
SELECT c.[id],c.[curr],c.[rate],c.[date]    
FROM [curr_rate] c, (SELECT curr, MAX(date) AS rate_date FROM [curr_rate] 
      GROUP BY curr) t
WHERE c.date = t.rate_date AND c.curr = t.curr
ORDER BY c.[curr] ASC
```

**Is it possible to write a query without sub-queries and join's with derived tables?**

Answer (score 1):

No, I think not.  Do you have an index on CURR, and date?

Comment: To choose a PRIMARY INDEX for the table - it's a sub task for this issue.
I think PRIMARY INDEX should contains from CURR and DATE fileds.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting out your indexes is probably more critical than SQL syntax in tuning this query.

It might be worth comparing the subquery approach against a CTE:

```
;WITH currCTE
AS
(
        SELECT id
               ,curr
               ,rate
               ,date
               ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY curr
                                   ORDER BY date desc
                                  ) AS rn
        FROM [curr_rate]
)
SELECT id
       ,curr
       ,rate
       ,date
FROM currCTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

If the table PK is on `id`, and rows are always added to the table in date order, you may get better performance by using `id` in the `ORDER BY` clause of the ranking function rather than date.

Comment: it was just a question/task - pre-interview for the job.
Now, I think there is no a decision withot sub-query and join's for the task.

Answer (score 1):

Your query does not use a subquery, so no need to change that.  A subquery is a SELECT query that returns a single value and is nested inside a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement, or inside another subquery. A subquery can be used anywhere an expression is allowed. See [Subquery Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213252%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Your query is using a derived table, also called an inline view, which you have named "t".

I would start by getting rid of the ancient join syntax:

```
SELECT 
    c.[id],c.[curr],c.[rate],c.[date]    
    FROM [curr_rate] c
        INNER JOIN (SELECT
                        curr, MAX(date) AS rate_date
                        FROM [curr_rate] 
                        GROUP BY curr
                   ) t ON c.curr = t.curr AND c.date = t.rate_date 
    ORDER BY c.[curr] ASC
```

but it will have the same execution plan.  You could just move the derived table into a CTE, but that is just about the same as a derived table.

The query would probably run faster if you created an indexed view on:

```
SELECT
    curr, MAX(date) AS rate_date
    FROM [curr_rate] 
    GROUP BY curr
```

with an index on curr+MAX(date).  If you would then have an index on [curr_rate].curr+date, your query would have better performance and be:

```
SELECT 
    c.[id],c.[curr],c.[rate],c.[date]    
    FROM [curr_rate] c
        INNER JOIN [curr_rate_max_view] t ON c.curr = t.curr AND c.date = t.rate_date 
    ORDER BY c.[curr] ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you can avoid the sub-select, but you can avoid the join and even the `group by`:

```
SELECT id, curr, rate, date
FROM curr_rate r
WHERE date = (
       SELECT MAX(date)
         FROM curr_rate
        WHERE curr = r.curr
      )
ORDER BY curr ASC
```

I have no idea how this will perform.

Comment: This query was my first decision, but I guess that my query would be better in perfomance (more faster).

Who knows, which one is more perfomance (better)?

Comment: It is extremely difficult to tell, @Sirius. You should always test queries for performance.